# Disable initial search when accessing kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

simple question regarding kibana 4.

When you navigate to the kibana page, by default it queries "*" for the last 15 minutes in a certain index.

Is there a way to disable this automatic search? I checked the advanced settings but didn't see anything obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set kibana.defaultAppId in de kibana.yml file to "settings". This opens the settings-page at startup, so no query gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `discover:searchOnPageLoad` in advanced settings.